# How to find different set of two vectors with no repetitions?

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing the code to return the data in `v1` that is not in `v2` vector, with no repetitions using C++.

```
std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
```

However, when my input v1,v2 are

```
v1=[137   138   139   140   141   142   143   144   148   150   157   158   161]
v2=[138   157   150   140   137   158   141   139   143   148]
```

The output results in unexpected solution as

```
diff=[   137   139   140   141   142   143   144   148   150   161]
```

While, my expected solution must be

```
diff=[  142   144   161]
```

What should I correct my function? Thanks

Comment: If you read e.g. [this `std::set_difference` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) you will see that it "Copies the elements from the **sorted** range [first1, last1) which are not found in the **sorted** range [first2, last2) to the range beginning at d_first". And that is exactly what it have done. Note the emphasis I added, about the data being **sorted** for *both* ranges.

Comment: So, how should I achieve my expected result. I know some function in MATLAB as `set_diff` can achieve my expected result

Comment: Make sure that *both* vectors are [sorted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: The algorithm assumes **both** sequences are sorted. Your example data doesn't satisfy that prerequisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2 needs to be sorted.  As does v1 (which it is). The function `set_difference` assumes both vectors are sorted.

The algorithm only has to walk each vector once, and only needs to compare the current cursor of each vector.  This is a significant performance improvement, and space saving from an algorithm which worked with arbitrary inputs.

Answer (score 1):

std::set_difference:

> Copies the elements from the sorted range [first1, last1) which are
> not found in the sorted range [first2, last2) to the range beginning
> at d_first
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference

You must sort your vectors, before difference them

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method:

```
std::set_difference(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                        std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
```

It's called `set_difference` for a reason :)

Just use `set` containers instead of your `vector` ones. They will make sure that your data is sorted and that the algorithm is successful.